# How to create dynamic positioned div on click of a card in react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, dynamic

I am working on a movie app task where when we click on a movie card, a detailed div will open above the list of the card row, the challenge is it should work like when we click on a card of a second row it should open in between first row and second row.

```
const MoviesList = () => {
  const boxData = [
    {
      value: "1",
    },
    {
      value: "2",
    },
    {
      value: "3",
    },
    {
      value: "4",
    },
    {
      value: "5",
    },
    {
      value: "6",
    },
    {
      value: "7",
    },
    {
      value: "8",
    },
    {
      value: "9",
    },
    {
      value: "10",
    },
  ];
  const boxWrap = {
    display: "flex",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    width: "100%",
    gap: "20px",
    marginTop: "20px",
  };
  const box = {
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    display: "flex",
    flex: "0 1 178px",
    border: "1px solid",
    height: "200px",
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div
        className="boxOnActive"
        style={{ width: "100%", height: "300px", border: "1px solid" }}
      >
        {boxData.map((data, id) => {
          return (
            <div className="box" style={box}>
              {data.value}
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

I have tried creating the dynamic div section which will show the data on above the list but when we need to show it in between row I couldn't make it.
[example image to understand the scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lC1O2.png)

Comment: Could you provide a link of a photo to understand more ?

Comment: yes, sure.  here it is. https://prnt.sc/QqCs04wNk-e4

Comment: @NuhaAl-sameai did you check?